# MongoDB - Mongoose - Can only call the controllers save method once. Then it never saves again

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

SEE EDIT DOWN BELOW PLEASE

What I am doing is calling the controllers save function via a post request. When I run the method for the first time is seems to save the 2 objects I made. And then it redirects me to the good route. But when I go back post the same POST request. It gives me the console.log's but never actually saves them.

The router:

```
app.post('/new', function(req, res, next){
  poll.newPoll(req, res, next);
  next();
}, function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/ok');
})
```

Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Schema for the polls
var pollSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  hash: String
});

var Poll = mongoose.model('Poll', pollSchema);

module.exports = Poll;
```

And controller:

```
var Poll = require('../modules/poll.js');
var hash = require('randomstring');

var randomHash = hash.generate({
  length: 5
});

//Function for creating new polls
module.exports.newPoll = function(req, res, next){
    var createdPoll = new Poll({title: "Wazap", hash: randomHash});
    var secondPoll = new Poll({title: "Ok", hash: randomHash});
    createdPoll.save(function (err, createdPoll) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return handleError(err);
      }
      console.log("New Poll saved");
    });

    secondPoll.save(function (err, secondPoll) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return handleError(err);
      }
      console.log("New Poll saved");
    });
}
```

Mongoose initialization:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//controllers
var poll = require('./controllers/poll.js');

//Mongostuff
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/pollr');
```

mongod log:

```
2016-08-11T14:51:38.142+0200 I COMMAND  [conn3] command pollr.polls command: insert { insert: "polls", documents: [ { title: "Wazap", hash: "pxeZP", _id: ObjectId('57ac74d997df31a423f20049'), __v: 0 } ], ordered: false, writeConcern: { w: 1 } } ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:40 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1, W: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 197ms
2016-08-11T14:51:38.143+0200 I COMMAND  [conn4] command pollr.polls command: insert { insert: "polls", documents: [ { title: "Ok", hash: "pxeZP", _id: ObjectId('57ac74d997df31a423f2004a'), __v: 0 } ], ordered: false, writeConcern: { w: 1 } } ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:40 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1 }, acquireWaitCount: { w: 1 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { w: 143945 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } p
```

Only when i delete all my data in the database it can save again. I hope this is enough info to give. I have searched on google for more than 2 hours to search for a solution but it did not give me one. It is probably something stupid I did or I overlooked something.

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

Apparantly it is saving, but not documenting it in the logs. If I only knew haha. Is there something I could do about this?

Comment: try replace this `var Poll = require('../modules/poll.js');` with `var Poll = mongoose.model('Poll');` in your controller and see..

Comment: @JAG it only gives me another error: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Poll".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following method for creating multiple documents at the same time. It uses an array to hold the documents and then passes that array to the create method which has a callback that can be used to call an error or do something with the resulting saved documents.

```
//Function for creating new polls

module.exports.newPoll = function(req, res, next){
    var docs = [{title: "Wazap", hash: randomHash}, {title: "Ok", hash: randomHash}];
    Poll.create(docs, function (err, wazap, ok) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return handleError(err);
        }
        console.log("Saved Wazap :" + wazap + " Saved Ok: " + ok)
    });
}
```

I have added the saved documents to the console.log so you can check their _id as well to ensure they are unique.

Comment: Thanks, but its not a fix to the problem im having haha